# webpack.optimize.UglifyJSPlugin is producing junk JavaScript

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, webpack-2

Building my ES6 react project under OSX El Capitan using Webpack is a breeze. Something very weird happens when I do the same build on our pre-production environment, the built file comes out like this:

```
webpackJsonp([0],{102:function(module,exports,__webpack_require__) ... 
...
var _createClass=function(){
    function defineProperties(target,props){
        for(;0<props.length;0++){
            ...
        }
    ...
}
...
```

Take particular note of that for loop: `for(;0<props.length;0++)`. That is very broken. What am I doing wrong? My config from UglifyJSPlugin:

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    comments: false,
    mangle: false,
    compress: {
        warnings: false
    }
})
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Full Webpack Config:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        isearch: 'components/isearch/index.js',
        reactbundle: ['react', 'react-dom', 'whatwg-fetch', 'debounce-promise', 'deep-assign', 'redux', 'react-redux']
    },
    output: {
        publicPath: '/assets/components/',
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'style-loader', options: { includePaths: [] } },
                    { loader: 'css-loader', options: { includePaths: [], modules: false } },
                    { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { includePaths: [] } }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.gif$/,
                exclude: '/node_modules/',
                use: [{ loader: 'file-loader', options: { name: '[path][name].[hash].[ext]', context: 'react' } }]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.scss'] },
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['components'], {
            root: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../public/assets'),
            verbose: true,
            dry: false
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('reactbundle'),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
            }
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            comments: false,
            mangle: false,
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            }
        })
    ]
};
```

Build Environment on which this fails: **Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS**

Comment: seems like i is replaced by 0. Show us the whole config file